# How to read Mono Audio value from setting in swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiotoolbox

Basically I'm trying to detect Mono Audio value is On/Off pragmatically in my swift based project.

I want to read Mono Audio value is On/Off in user setting.

So based on that value I will prompt user that your Mono Audio setting is off please enable it from Settings

And redirect user to Audio Settings.

> Settings > General > Accessibility > Mono Audio

But I am not sure how to read this property.

I have checked AudioToolbox framework but there I haven't find any thing.

[Audio toolbox](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audiobalancefade)

I tried in Accessibility framework but no luck.

```
var isAccessibilityElement: Bool { get set }
```

Any Idea or ref how to get this detail via code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Accessibility Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/1615123-ismonoaudioenabled) contains a method:

```
static var isMonoAudioEnabled: Bool { get }
```

It returns a Boolean value indicating whether system audio is set to mono.
Isn't that, what you are looking for?

Comment: Ya actually I fond that with `UIAccessibilityIsMonoAudioEnabled()` function same like you posted here. Thanks for your answer. but I have one more question here if you can help me on that ?

Comment: Can I directly Jump to Settings->General->Accessibility to On/Off this setting with openURL() method ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. I think jumps into Preferences App were possible in earlier versions of iOS but are currently discouraged by Apple. The only exception may be an App's own preferences screen.